# Laravel Form Validation - array

Tags: php, laravel

I need to validate some input using Request rules() method.

This is my view(+8 more fields):

```
{!! Form::open(['method'=>'POST','route' => ['method.store']]) !!}

@for($add = 0; $add < $number; $add++ )
    {!! Form::text('first_name[]') !!}
@endfor

@include('part.error')
{!! Form::submit('Add') !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

The user can chose how many to add(max. 10). The for loop is including a partial but I did rewrite it to include only this one field just for readability.

This is my dd($this->first_name); output:

```
array:3 [▼
  0 => ""
  1 => ""
  2 => ""
]
```

This is what i got so far in my Request:

```
public function rules()
{
    for ($i = 0; $i < $this->number; $i ++)
    {
        $rules['first_name.' . $i] = 'required' 
        ...
        ...
    }
return $rules;
}
```

I did try with:

```
$rules['first_name[' . $i.']'] = 'required';
```

The only thing i get so far is the:

```
htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given...
```

in my partial(form-fields).

Comment: You are passing an array as the first parameter to Form::text() as the error says. I guess what you are trying to achieve is Form::text('first_name' . $add). Also if this is your exact code, do not forget to capitalize the 'f' in "form::open"

Comment: Thanks for answering. And there is no problem with the form, it gets passed well to the Controller and saved to the Model. I need the first_name[], so I can store multiple inputs. The error is given by the rules() method and I don't know why. Without the validation, there is no problem. But still I need to validate it somehow. Edit: Yea, i didn't copy it right to the post. It's still good in the project.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding. Is this you entire function for rules? if not would you share the whole code for rules()?

Comment: That is all i have inside the rules() method. The dots replace other form fields, like 'second_name', 'last_name'. Like 8 more fields, same as the 'first_name' array.

Comment: Check my answer. I think that should solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the name of your fields. When the validation fails and it redirects to your form, it cannot tell which one of your fields failed since they do not have a unique name.

Add the id of each field to the field's name like so:

```
@for($add = 0; $add < $number; $add++ )
    {!! Form::text("first_name[$add]") !!}
@endfor
```

Also if you want the fields to be automatically filled with the old entries after the validation fails, pass a null value as the default text for your text field like so:

```
{!! Form::text("first_name[$add]", null) !!}
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: Wow, i really thought this will affect my store method, but it didn't. Thank you for explaining and solving.